# How to pass string instead of string argument in android sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am creating a database in which I need to show data of previous day.

```
    Long test=  System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60;

    DateFormat dateFormattest= DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    String dateFilter= dateFormattest.format(test);
    Log.v("initial",  dateFilter);

   // String[] args={dateFilter.toString()};

    cursor=dba.query(Utils.Table_Name,new String[]{Utils.Id_Name,Utils.Food_Name,Utils.Calorie_Name,
        Utils.Date_Name},Utils.Date_Name+"=?",new String[]{dateFilter},null,null,Utils.Date_Name+ " DESC");
   // Log.v("sentvalue", args+"");
```

I have correct value at datefilter at 
logcatbut the value of initial is nov 8,2016
but at sentvalue the logcat is Ljava.lang.String;@501eb6

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print String array object that's why logcat is `Ljava.lang.String;@501eb6`.

Try like below to print value of first object of array.

```
Log.v("sentvalue", args[0]);
```

Try to query like below.

```
String[] projection = {utils.Id_Name,
                      Utils.Food_Name,
                      Utils.Calorie_Name,
                      Utils.Date_Name};

String selection =  Utils.Date_Name + "< ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) };
String orderBy = Utils.Date_Name+ " DESC";     

Cursor cursor = db.query(
        Utils.Table_Name,                         // The table to query
        projection,                               // The columns to return
        selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
        selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
        null,                                     // don't group the rows
        null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
        orderBy                                   // The sort order
        );
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.shailendra.navtest, PID: 24953
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

Comment: I want to select it as datefilter. How to I put date filter there because it doesnot take datefilter parameter... it askes for string array

Comment: In Which format your are inserting `Date_Name` in database? You should use that format as `selectionArgs` to query from database.

Comment: i have date format stored in epoch time. How can I filter it so that i can get all data stored before that day

Comment: Check my updated answer for that. you need to use `<` operator in `selection` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` in `selectionArgs` to get all data stored before today (change time mills according to your need).